# NHibernate.MappingException'Could not compile the mapping document: OrmEx.Customer.hbm.xml

Tags: nhibernate

I have a problem with Nhibernate mapping. Can you help me?

[image]

and that is my Customer.hbm.xml enter code here:

[image]

And soon as that is App Config

[image]

I use to sqlserver 2012 and NHibernate 5.0.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mapping file has different namespace than your class, I suppose `QuickStart` assembly does not exists:

```
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
              assembly="OrmEx"
              namespace="OrmEx">
```